# Python 3.4 SpeechRecognition 1.1.3 Error

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am attempting to implement speech recognition in one of my programs and have settled upon using the SpeechRecognition 1.1.3 library to accomplish this.

The code that I am attempting to run, and the associated error is this:

```
>>> r = sr.Recognizer()
>>> with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
...     audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\speechrecognition-1.1.3-py3.4.egg\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 201, in listen
    return AudioData(source.RATE, self.samples_to_flac(source, frame_data))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\speechrecognition-1.1.3-py3.4.egg\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 124, in samples_to_flac
    if system == "Windows" and platform.machine() in set("i386", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"): # Windows NT, use the bundled FLAC conversion utility
TypeError: set expected at most 1 arguments, got 4
```

I already have gone through and downloaded the correct versions of each of the required downloads.
I have googled it extensively and have not been able to find a reason for this.
This, and another error which stop me from transcribing specific Wav files, is impeding my project, so if someone could help that would be appreciated.

I am running Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just opened a pull request for the project on this - but the problem was an update for backwards compatibility a week ago. You can either pull my version from:
https://github.com/develra/speech_recognition/

or

go into the speech_recognition/**init**.py file and change

if system == "Windows" and platform.machine() in set("i386", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"): # Windows NT, use the bundled FLAC conversion utility

to

if system == "Windows" and platform.machine() in set(["i386", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"]): # Windows NT, use the bundled FLAC conversion utility

and

elif system == "Linux" and platform.machine() in set("i386", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"):

to

elif system == "Linux" and platform.machine() in set(["i386", "x86", "x86_64", "AMD64"]):